# Summing using Inline for loop vs normal for loop

Tags: python, for-loop

I'm trying to sum a list named **mpg** with the entry **'cty'** (converted from a dictionary).

Sample data:

```
[{'': '1',   'trans': 'auto(l5)',   'drv': 'f',   'cty': '18'},  {'': '2',   'trans': 'manual(m5)',   'drv': 'f',   'cty': '21'}]
```

I tried 2 ways of doing this:

1. This gives the error that float object is not iterable.

```
for d in mpg:
    sum(float(d['cty']))
```

2. No problem with this one.

```
sum(float(d['cty']) for d in mpg)
```

I understand that float objects are not iterable but isn't the 2nd method just an example of list comprehension of the 1st one?

Why does the second option work but not the first?

Comment: The `float` function works on a single value and not a list, it will also in no case return a list so `sum` can not use the result

Comment: No, a list comphrension creates a list, then you pass that list to `sum`. In 2. you actually use a *generator expression*, which is passed to `sum`. But it works the same way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sum()` takes an **iterable** as an argument and sums all items of that iterable. A simple float or integer is not a list and therefore not iterable.

- In example 1, you iterate through each item of your list of dictionaries, but then only pass a single float (the float value of the current dictionary) to your function, resulting in `sum(123)`, which then returns an error.
- In example 2, you first iterate through your whole list of dictionaries and extract the values you need into a new list. If you stored `float(d['cty']) for d in mpg` in a new variable, it would create a list. If you now pass that list, the function results in `sum([123, 456, 789])`, which returns the desired value.

Comment: *No list is involved here*, actually, The OP used a *generator expression*, which results in a generator. `sum` takes *any iterable*, not just lists.

Answer (score 0):

The second one works because the list comprehension constructs a list prior to trying to evaluate the sum, but the first way tries to pass `float(d['cty'])` to the `sum`. But that's just a float rather than an iterable (which is what `sum` needs). See this modification of the first way:

```py
lst = []
for d in mpg:
    lst.append(float(d['cty']))
sum(lst)
```

Answer (score 0):

Two ways to solve the problem:

1.

```
i = 0
for d in mpg:
    i += float(d['cty'])
```

2. 

```
x = sum([float(d['cty']) for d in mpg])
```